# Free multiplatform oscilloscope with custom oscilloscope support

Tags: oscilloscope, software

I have a USB oscilloscope (works with command line) and I want to have a oscilloscope GUI to see the samples and preferentially have options that most oscilloscopes have (e.g. trigger, frequency calculator).

Do you know any software where I can create custom oscilloscopes in order to use the GUI with values readed by my own (by creating an adapter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many o'scopes have some hardware connected by USB to a standard computer which displays the results using some open-source software.

Perhaps you could tweak some of that open-source software to work with your scope?

If that's too much work, perhaps you could buy an "open hardware" oscilloscope that already works great with that open-source software?

There's a bunch of "open hardware" o'scopes listed at http://opencircuits.com/Oscilloscope .

Answer (score 1):

You can try to search [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/), [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), [github](https://github.com/), [Google Code](http://code.google.com/) and other FLOSS repository hosting sites.
If you can use the oscilloscope from the commandline (and you have sufficient documentation), you could use any modern scripting language (like [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260905/whats-the-best-easiest-gui-library-for-ruby) or [Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) ) to write your own GUI (and send shell-commands in the background).